# Why does List<T> declare GetEnumerator() and IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()?

Tags: c#, interface, ienumerable, ienumerator, explicit-interface

Why does List define these three methods?

```
    public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
        => new Enumerator(this);

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
        => new Enumerator(this);

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => new Enumerator(this);
```

They are all doing the same thing. Wouldn't it be enough to just have this:

```
public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
        => new Enumerator(this);
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation

Comment: `Enumerator GetEnumerator()` lets it return a struct enumerator for use in `foreach` loops, without allocating. `IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` lets it implement the `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()` method from the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, so you can do `IEnumerable<T> x = new List<T>(); foreach (var item in x) ...`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Wouldn't it be enough to just have this:
>
> ```
> public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
>        => new Enumerator(this);
> ```

No, it wouldn't, because that wouldn't implement either `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerable`, where the `GetEnumerator()` methods have return types of `IEnumerator<T>` and `IEnumerator` respectively.

The return types have to match in order to implement the interface.

Indeed, it's easy to test this for yourself:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public Enumerator GetEnumerator() =>
        new Enumerator();

    // Implement this fully so we can concentrate on IEnumerable<T>
    public struct Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        public T Current => default;
        object IEnumerator.Current => default;
        public bool MoveNext() => true;
        public void Reset() {}
        public void Dispose() {}
    }
}
```

That gives errors of:

- error CS0738: 'MyList<T>' does not implement interface member 'IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()'. 'MyList<T>.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IEnumerator<T>'.
- error CS0738: 'MyList<T>' does not implement interface member 'IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'MyList<T>.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'IEnumerator'.